# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) how to send CSRF token from frontend to backend?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, fetch-api

I have a Django project, where I need to send a date string from frontend to backend. At frontend I am using the javascript fetch method

```
async function getCustomerInDeliveryDate(deliveryDate : String) {
    const response = await fetch('getCustomerInTripDate', {
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            deliveryDate :  deliveryDate
        }),
    });
    return response
}
```

From Django backend I currently implemented a simple method that returns a string back to frontend

```
class GetCustomerInTripDate(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Backend received call from front end!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        return JsonResponse({'data': ['hello', 'world']}, status = 200)
```

The error that I receive when I try to send to backend is

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /staff/getCustomerInTripDate
```

I am not sure how to send the csrf token. The research I have done so far all indicated that credentials should be set as "same-origin", and I have tried it but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is Cross Site Request Forgery( CSRF )

You have detailed explanation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/

Long story short, try adding {% csrf_token %} protection in django templates.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} <----- ADD THIS
......everything else goes here
</form>
```

Or if you dont use django templates try adding csrf decorator to your view.
I think it should be something like this:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator<----- ADD THIS
    
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')<----- ADD THIS
class GetCustomerInTripDate(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Backend received call from front end!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        return JsonResponse({'data': ['hello', 'world']}, status = 200)
```

I think this should work, hope it helps.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `{% csrf_token %}` into the template.

If you are using a normal HTML form, place it inside the form.

```html
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you are using Ajax it doesn't matter where you place it you just have to add it to the POST data

```js
submitData = {
  
  // other data

  'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
};

$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'some_url',
  data: submitData,
  success: function(data){
    // do things
  },
  error: function(event,xhr,settings,errorText){
    // do error things
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is by default stored as a cookie.
So you should retrieve the cookie with javascript, then send the token it.

Or you could make a restful endpoint.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct understood that csrf is not required if endpoint is restful? And why not?